# Unhide login popup while clicking outside of Div

Tags: jquery, popup

I'm using the bellow script to get `login dialogue box` when the user click's anywhere inside the homepage.

```
<?php
 if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
 { 
    echo '<body>';
 } else {
    echo '<body onClick="showSmartRegisterDialog(); return false;">';
 }
?>
```

If i click anywhere outside the login form div, the login window is appearing again. How to solve this?

Did anyone came through this problem ?

Solution to solve this highly appreciate-able....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the onclick after showing the dialog. ;)

```
echo '<body onclick="showSmartRegisterDialog(); this.onclick = \'\'; return false;">';
```

**edit:**

Try changing this:

```
Event.observe($$('#smartlogin .overlay-modal')[0], 'click', function(event){
    $$('#smartlogin .error')[0].style.display != 'none' ? smartLogin.closeError() : smartLogin.hideSmartDialogs();
});
```

to this:

```
Event.observe($$('#smartlogin .overlay-modal')[0], 'click', function(event){
    if($$('#smartlogin .error')[0].style.display != 'none') smartLogin.closeError();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jānis.... Your answer worked like a charm.. Now the only issue is popup window is getting hide when i clicking outside of popup window... Please help me to solve this too... jscript i'm using for this is from http://www.cap365.com/js/itoris/smartlogin/smartlogin.js

Comment: You are the man... It's working awesome.. I searched more than a day to solve this.. Thank you once again.. Keep up the good work....

Comment: Hi Janis... I'm having one more trouble please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289253/magento-issue-in-using-if-else-loop-to-call-body-tag