# Magento issue in using if else loop to call body tag

Tags: magento

I'm using ajax login script in my store, so i'm using below script to show `Login Dialogue box` is user didn't logged in

```
<?php
 if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
 { 
  echo '<body>';
  } 
 else {
echo '<body onClick="showSmartRegisterDialog(); return false;">';
}  ?>
```

instead of default

`<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>`

Now the only problem is i didn't used php code `<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>` to call class name. so pages are not loading properly.

so i modified above mentioned to code to this,

```
<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
{ 
echo '<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>'; } else {    echo '<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?> onClick="showSmartRegisterDialog(); return false;">'; }
?>
```

Now my frontend is showing a blank screen. Did anyone have a idea where i'm going wrong ?
Please give me your idea to solve this

Comment: is this question related to jQuery?

Comment: instead of `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()` use `$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()` inside blocks and templates and `Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()` everywhere else. Looks better and more logically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using php tags inside php , try:

```
<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) { ?>
<body <?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<?php } else { ?>
<body <?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?> onClick="showSmartRegisterDialog(); return false;">
<?php } ?>
```